# getRequestDispatcher(.).forward(req,res) throws java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: servlets, websphere-8, requestdispatcher

I have upgraded my Servlet from 2.4 to 3.0 and deployed my application on Websphere 8.5.5.8. Application Server starts properly.
When I try to access my `home.jsp` page in browser it throws:

> Controller Main Error OG1000SRVE0190E: File not found: /servlet/com.platform7.affina.operations.servlet.ValidateLoginUser

When I try to debug, code hits my Main Controller Servlet (which is in same package) but inside Controller servlet class I am calling:

```
this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("Servlet/com.platform7.affina.operations.servlet.ValidateLoginUser").forward(request, response);
```

Which throws:

> FileNotFoundException for  Servlet/com.platform7.affina.operations.servlet.ValidateLoginUser.

But `ValidateLoginUser` is in the same package and classes folder location!

Folder structure:

```
\NEED4SPEEDCell02\operations_1.ear\OperationsWeb.war\WEB-INF\classes\com\platform7\affina\operations\servlet
```

`ControllerMain.class` and `ValidateLoginUser.class` are in same servlet package.

my `Web.xml` file:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servletMain</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.platform7.affina.operations.servlet.ControllerMain</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servletMain</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/controllerMain</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So when I access my URL: it hits `ControllerMain.class` but inside this class I am calling another servlet which is not part of `web.xml` but is located in same package of `ControllerMain.class`.

When I print realpath: `this.getServletContext().getRealPath("/"));`

I get:

> C:\WebSphere858\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\installedApps\NEED4SPEEDCell02\operations_1.ear\OperationsWeb.war

I tried using `getNamedDispatcher(..)` too but throws: `null`.

**Same code works fine on Websphere 7 and even works on Websphere 8.5.5.5**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to [security reasons](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21959083) the default setting for `com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.disallowServeServletsByClassname` property has been changed.

> Please Note:This APAR has changed the default value of the
>   WebContainer custom property
>   `com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.disallowServeServletsByClassname` from **false** to
>   **true** so that no security threat could occur. Prior to this change, it
>   was up to the developer to remember to change the custom property to
>   true before deploying into production.
>
> Property Name:
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.disallowServeServletsByClassname Description:
>   **If set to true, disallows the use of serveServletsByClassnameEnabled
>   at the application server level, overriding any setting of
>   serveServletsByClassnameEnabled at the application level**. This
>   property affects all applications. Values: true(default)/false

You will need to add that custom property to the Web Container and set it to **false** for serving servlets by class name.

But as BalusC suggested, you should add your servlet to `web.xml` in the form:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servletMain</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.platform7.affina.operations.servlet.ValidateLoginUser</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servletMain</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/validateLoginUser</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and change that forward to:

```
this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/validateLoginUser").forward(request, response);
```

And do the same with your other class from the same package.

Comment: Brilliant Gas, Sorry for late reply as it took lot of deployment time after the changes you suggested. So thought of trying first before commenting. Many many thanks for your solution. It works combination of both the solutions, yours and BalusC. I have to change all my servlet calling pattern getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("...") and web.xml accordingly. Many Thanks again.

Comment: Nice to heat that. If you add your servlet to `web.xml`, and change dispatcher to use mapping name, then you no longer need to set that property and to set `serveServletsByClassnameEnabled` in the `ibm-web-ext.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be relying on the legacy `InvokerServlet` which is known to have major security holes. This was deprecated in Tomcat 5 and clones (WebSphere 4) and removed in Tomcat 7 and clones (WebSphere 6).

You're not supposed to use it anymore. Just map the servlet on a normal URL pattern and invoke it. Assuming that the servlet is mapped on an URL pattern of `/validateLoginUser` via `@WebServlet("/validateLoginUser")` annotation on the servlet class, or via `<url-pattern>/validateLoginUser</url-pattern>` in `web.xml` mapping on the servlet, then you can get a request dispatcher on it as below:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/validateLoginUser");
```

Or, just refactor shared code to a plain Java class with a method and invoke it the usual Java way. It's these days kind of weird to have shared validation logic tight coupled in a servlet.

#### See also:

- [How to invoke a servlet without mapping in web.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031018/how-to-invoke-a-servlet-without-mapping-in-web-xml)

Comment: Thanks for your kind help Balusc. Problem is, my Company doesn't want to do major code change. Else I will preferably remove all these old code legacy pattern of web.xml and remove tight coupling and go ahead with annotations. We need to support websphere 8.5.5.8 which needs Servlet 3. Original code was return using Servlet 2.4

Same code works with Websphere 7 and even works on Websphere 8.5.5.5 but its started complaining with 8.5.5.8 :(

Comment: Thanks BalusC, you are right and your solution works too.

Answer (score 0):

To make above upgrade working, I did few other changes as below for future references.

Mainly, I have to change binding files for websphere.
Previously, I had two bindings **ibm-web-bnd.xmi** and **ibm-web-ext.xmi**

*ibm-web-bnd.xmi*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<com.ibm.ejs.models.base.bindings.webappbnd:WebAppBinding xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:com.ibm.ejs.models.base.bindings.webappbnd="webappbnd.xmi" xmi:id="WebAppBinding_1226331113121" virtualHostName="default_host">
  <webapp href="WEB-INF/web.xml#WebApp"/>
    <resRefBindings xmi:id="ResourceRefBinding_1226331113121" jndiName="AffinaDataSource_pma">
      <bindingResourceRef href="WEB-INF/web.xml#ResourceRef_AffinaDataSource_pma"/>
    </resRefBindings>
</com.ibm.ejs.models.base.bindings.webappbnd:WebAppBinding>
```

*ibm-web-ext.xmi*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<com.ibm.ejs.models.base.extensions.webappext:WebAppExtension 
    xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" 
    xmlns:com.ibm.ejs.models.base.extensions.webappext="webappext.xmi" 
    xmi:id="WebAppExtension_1226331113121"
    serveServletsByClassnameEnabled="true">
  <webApp href="WEB-INF/web.xml#WebApp"/>
  <jspAttributes xmi:id="JSPAttribute_1226331113121" name="reloadEnabled" value="true"/>
  <jspAttributes xmi:id="JSPAttribute_1226331113122" name="reloadInterval" value="10"/>
</com.ibm.ejs.models.base.extensions.webappext:WebAppExtension>
```

So as per servlet3 and Websphere 8.5.5.8, I change to replace above two .xmi files with **ibm-web-bnd.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-bnd xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-bnd_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

  <virtual-host name="default_host"/>
  <resource-ref name="AffinaDataSourceAlias_pma" binding-name="AffinaDataSource_pma"/>

</web-bnd>
```

and then while installing application on Websphere 8.5.5.8, it use to throw outofmemmory error, so to fix that I change below max memory parameter from 256m to 512m in wsadmin.bat

*C:\WebSphere858\AppServer\bin\wsadmin.bat*

```
set PERFJAVAOPTION=-Xms256m -Xmx512m -Xquickstart
```

Hope this helps.