# What exactly does "context" mean in context-(in)sensitive analysis?

Tags: java, static-analysis, dataflow

This question was [asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918083/what-exactly-is-a-context-in-java) but the answers are very generic. I am interested to know what **context** means in the context of static code analysis, specifically with Java and when used in conjunction with the term *context (in)sensitive analysis*.

For example [this paper](http://suif.stanford.edu/papers/pods05.pdf) makes extensive use of "context" in this context. In fact I have not found a decent definition of context yet.

Comment: I'm not sure it has a well defined meaning. A context sensitive static analysis may take into account the calling occurrences (or some abstraction of the call stack) of the currently analyzed function.

Comment: The meaning of "context" is itself highly context-dependent. For example, one similar meaning can be found at the [Wikipedia entry on data-flow analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-flow_analysis).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The word “context” in the question you linked to does not appear to be used to describe a static analysis, so yours is indeed another question. I do not think that **that** question's answer are “generic”. But they are definitely not the specific answer you are looking for.

A [context-sensitive analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-flow_analysis#Sensitivities) is an interprocedural analysis that considers the calling context when analyzing the target of a function call.

Here is an example of how a context-sensitive analysis might work:

```
int a,b;

int *x;

void f(void)
{
  ++*x;
}

int main(){
  x = &a;
  f();

  x = &b;
  f();
}
```

This is not Java, but your question is mostly about context-sensitivity in dataflow analyses, so I hope it won't be too disturbing.

A context-sensitive analyzer analyses `f()` (at least) twice in this program, because it is called from from call sites. This makes it precise, as the effects of `f()` are quite different each time. A context-sensitive analysis can infer that `a==1` and `b` is unchanged after the first call, and that both `a` and `b` are `1` after the second call. Context-sensitivity also makes the analysis expensive.

A context-insensitive analysis would only analyze `f()` once, and would typically only produce information of the sort “`f()` modifies `a` or `b`, thus after any call to `f()`, the contents of both these variables are unknown”.