# Button Start New Activity cannot start?

Tags: java, android

i have created apps in eclipse with target sdk in API 15 and. I want to make button start new activity. i have created that code but i have a problem. when i run in on my phone ninetology stealh 2, when i click a button and my app has crash and my phone show me this :

"Unfortunately start"

i have tested it in others phone two and it show same problem. i also use more technique that i learn from thenewboston, vongella an other but still have same problem. here is my .xml and java code :-

1. menu.java

> ```
> package com.mytuturkiu.mytuturkiu;
>
> import android.app.Activity;
> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.view.View;                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
> import android.widget.Button;
> import android.content.Intent;
>
>     public class Menu extends Activity {
>
>       Button btnmodul;
>
>       @Override
>       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>           setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
>
>           btnmodul = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnmodul);      
>             btnmodul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>
>               @Override
>               public void onClick(View v) {
>           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>               Intent vokal = new Intent(v.getContext(),Modul_Vokal.class);
>               startActivity(vokal);
>           }
>       } );
>
>   }
>
>
>
> }
> ```

1. Modul_vokal.java

> package com.mytuturkiu.mytuturkiu;
>
> ```
> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.app.Activity;
> import android.view.Menu;
>
> public class Modul_Vokal extends Activity {
>
>   @Override
>   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>       setContentView(R.layout.activity_modul__vokal);
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
>       // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
>       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.modul__vokal, menu);
>       return true;
>   }
>
> }
> ```

1. AndroidManifest.xml

   ```
   <uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="14"
       android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

   <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <activity
           android:name="com.mytuturkiu.mytuturkiu.Menu"
           android:label="@string/app_name" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
       <activity
           android:name="com.mytuturkiu.mytuturkiu.Modul_Vokal"
           android:label="@string/title_activity_modul__vokal" >
       </activity>

   </application>
   ```

what problem with my apps?..

Comment: post the crash log and activity_menu.xml

Answer (score 1):

You should not do `v.getContext()`... You should use `getApplicationContext()`..

The View `v` is the view you clicked on. So `v.getContext()` returns the context which the view runs on. This is the issue.

I think using Application's context is better and doesn't cause an issue.

Comment: I have some problem to understand your answer

Comment: @blackbelt feel free to ask any question you have. I'm here to answer you.

Comment: Here are some resources for information about contexts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918083/what-exactly-is-a-context-in-java    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android   http://bountyforu.blogspot.in/2013/06/what-is-context-in-android.html

Comment: neither of the links you provide talk about "menu context"

Comment: I missed something in my answer. I'm correcting it now. Thanks for pointing out @blackbelt

Comment: @blackbelt I'm sorry. I thought it's something else. I will edit my answer to be correct. Thx

Comment: This still isn't the problem. `v.getContext()` returns the `Context` on which the `View` is running. In this case, it is the `Activity Context` which is what should be used to start a new `Activity`

Comment: @codeMagic well in this case it doesn't work. I never had problems with using `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: Why doesn't it work in this case? How do you know that's the problem? I didn't say that `getApplicationContext()` won't work

Comment: @codeMagic Well that's why all the answers on the SO are not getting accepted. It's just a try and fail. People post their suggestions. It may or may not solve the issue. We are not magicians and we don't do magic. If I was on the poster's computer I could solve it. But until we're here we only guess. right?

Comment: Easy friend. I was just pointing out why this doesn't solve it and why the `context` used should be fine. We can't know the problem without seeing the logcat. I have used `v.getContext()` and it works fine. What I wrote about the `Context` returned is from the Docs

Comment: @codeMagic I'm easy :) I read the docs too and corrected my answer. I don't say you're wrong.

Comment: Good, now we can have a friendly debate :) My point is that the `Context` returned by the `View` is the `Activity Context` which is generally used to start an `Activity` as in `MainActivity.this`. I'm not saying you're wrong either I just disagree which is why I deleted my similar answer

Comment: Well I'm not sure :) I'm not too professional in Android because I started it, Two-three months ago :) I just thought that it might be the problem. Turns out it wasn't :)

Comment: And that's fine, I was just giving you my opinion on it. That's why we are all here...to learn. I'm not claiming to have all the answers either but just adding my input so it may help

Answer (score 0):

You can add a function like this in your class:

```
  public class Menu extends Activity {

  Button btnmodul;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

      btnmodul = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnmodul);      
      btnmodul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            // CALL THE FUNCTION
            startMyActivity();
          }
      } );

  }

  private void startMyActivity(){
         Intent vokal = new Intent(this,Modul_Vokal.class);
         startActivity(vokal);
  }

}
```

The function is in your activity context and when you put "**this**" in the Intent constructor, it will take the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
 Intent vokal = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Modul_Vokal.class);
              startActivity(vokal);
```

in place of,

```
   Intent vokal = new Intent(v.getContext(),Modul_Vokal.class);
              startActivity(vokal);
```

It will definately work my friend.